# Woocommerce - Conditional for 'Featured?' Products

Tags: woocommerce

On a single product page I'd like to know if there's a conditional for detecting whether the current product has been marked as 'Featured'?

I've tried variations on:

```
if( has_term( 1, 'featured' ) ) { 
 etc ...
```

and

```
if( has_term( TRUE, 'featured' ) ) { 
 etc ...
```

No luck so far. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

```
$current_product = wc_get_product( get_the_ID() );

$current_product_featured_query = $current_product->featured;

if( $current_product_featured_query == "yes" ) {...
*... this product is indeed, featured!*
```

does the job.